# Starting vim at top of the screen

Tags: macos, vim, vimrc, macvim

I'm an avid MacVim user and every time I launch it the window starts about 2 rows too far down on the screen to where I have to drag it up to the top of my screen every time. Is there anything I can add in my .vimrc to make it start at the top every time?

EDIT:

For anyone having the same problem with a MBP (1440X900), if you `:set lines=49` it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

First result on Google for: macvim position window top

Gave me this:

http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=53

It seems to be a known issue with the way OS X handles window placement and Bjorn hasn't figured out a way around it yet.

Edit: Woops, in comment 8 he changed the status to 'fixed'... It was supposedly fixed only 9 days ago, and a snapshot build hasn't been released since then.. so if you just wait for the next release of Macvim it should be solved :-)

Comment: Could have done without the LMGTFY but thanks. I must have been phrasing my search wrong.

Comment: Sorry, don't meant to be condescending, I just find that site highly amusing :-)

Comment: haha, yeah, I agree with you.